# Choice of coordinates of Hamiltonian systems

Tags: momentum, symmetry, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

I read the wiki:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics

It says,

> The $q_i$ are called generalized coordinates, and are chosen so as to eliminate the constraints or to take advantage of the symmetries of the problem, and $p_1$ are their conjugate momenta.

Can anyone please point out what does it mean

1. to take advantage of symmetries
2. conjugate momenta

Not very understand what both mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Say you have a system which is spherically symmetric. That is, the
   only coordinate that can effect the physics around you is your
   distance $r$ from some origin. Then in many cases there is no need
   for you to also keep track of the coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$
   that determine your direction; no physics can depend on these
   parameters, so there's no reason to care (except to know that you
   are in 3-dimensional space, as this can change things from the 1D
   case). This is an example of a symmetry deciding which coordinates
   you should use. In this case, a good choice would be to only use a
   single generalized coordinate: $q_1 = r$.

   This is a very simple example, but the same principle applies in
   general: choose your coordinates with the problem you want to solve
   in mind! Symmetries can often greatly simplify your choice of
   coordinate system.
2. The conjugate momentum $p_i$ of a generalized coordinate $q_i$ is
   defined as $$p_i = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial
   \dot{q_i}},$$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Lagrangian. It is named as
   such because in most cases, the conjugate momentum will correspond
   to either the linear or angular momentum in your problem. (If you
   choose your generalized coordinates to be the regular Cartesian
   coordinates $(x,y,z)$, then the conjugate momenta will normally be
   the linear momenta; whereas if you choose your generalized
   coordinates to be spherical coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$, the
   conjugate momenta will correspond to the angular momenta.)

   To learn more about conjugate momenta, I recommend reading a
   [textbook on classical mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/189138922X) (Taylor is good, but there are many other good options as well), or checking out one of the
   many SE posts on the [Lagrangian/Hamiltonian formalisms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lagrangian-formalism).

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate momentum is the momentum associated with that coordinate.  Thus in cartesian coordinates, the momentum conjugate to the variable x is $$m\dot x$$
and etc.

A constraint is a restriction in the freedom of motion that typically reduces the number of coordinates necessary to describe the system.  Many texts point out that a rigid body is a good example of a system with constraints.  The constraints are that the distances between the particles that make up the system are constrained to be a certain distance apart from each other.  It is easy to point out that a rigid body composed of N particles does not need 3N coordinates to specify its position in space, but only six coordinates: 3 for the center of mass and 3 for the orientation.

If a coordinate does not show up in the Hamiltonian (or Lagrangian for that matter), then the momentum conjugate to that coordinate is a constant.  This may result from the symmetry of the system.

For example, with a central force problem, the symmetry of the problem results, in polar coordinates, with $$p_\theta$$ being a constant.